# Dask dashboard is empty

Tags: python, dask, dashboard, dask-distributed

I have several python scripts that run different Dask tasks from different databases and I used the Python multiprocessing module to run all of the Python scripts simultaneously. I checked with my task manager that the scripts are running parallelly and I was able to access my dask dashboard. However, my dask dashboard is not showing anything. Here is the screenshot of my dask dashboard.

[image: dask dashboard screenshot here]

This is my Python code snippet sample (simplified):

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup Dask Distributed Client
    client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=4)
    """
    call the scripts here and store it in a process list
    """
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
```

Comment: Have you debugged by running each script individually (do they write sucessfully to the dashboard)? And without more relevant code its impossible to tell whats going wrong. Is it form the multiprocess portion, dask, or something else? Can't tell without code.

Comment: @JasonChia If I were to run each of the scripts individually, then the dashboard will show the progress.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I did not explain my code good enough. I have 3 scripts that composed of a Python class object (A, B & C) where each of them will perform one dask process (count, mean and median). My database has data of 60 production lines and I need to process each of the production lines using the scripts. When I multiprocess 1 script, the dask dashboard will show progress. However, the dask dashboard is empty when I run all scripts.

Comment: As mentioned, it is impossible to debug your problem...without actually seeing any code....Can you put the section of code on how you call your dask processes from multiprocessing?

Comment: also - why use multiprocessing and dask at the same time? Dask is already parallelizing your code. you're making debugging very complicated and also introducing complexity that dask was designed to handle for you.

Comment: @JasonChia I wished I could share the code here but my code is too long. But I've managed to solve the problems. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining multiple processes with `Client()`, you are creating a default cluster in each process. The one in the main process will be the dashboard that you can see, and the others will also have dashboards, but at different ports. If you capture the stdout of the subprocesses, they would tell you on which ports.

This is likely not what you meant to do. If you want multiple processes to talk to a single cluster, you should create that cluster first, and then connect to it with something like `client("tcp://locaklhost:8786")`.

However, this all also raises the question, if you want to use dask, why are you also creating processes? Why not just let Dask take care of executing things, e.g., with `client.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers and replies. I've managed to solve it by defining a client with the dask-scheduler tcp (eg. client("tcp://192.168.x.xx:8786")) in the function of each of the scripts instead of setting a single client in my main.py. As for why I use multiprocessing and dask together, it was due to my company need to deals with lots of dask scripts simultaneously. In side each of the scripts, I need to process different huge dataframes made from different data queries from the client data warehouse. I use dask in each of the scripts to handle the huge dataframes and python multiprocessing module to simultaneously execute all of the scripts and handle them in a single cmd window.

Comment: Not sure if it the right approach as I'm still exploring Dask. I will be grateful if there is any other better alternatives or ideas.